How can I construct a semi-circle in urdf
Making a cylinder is easy.  How can I make a semi-circle shape?

Cylinders are easy because they are one of the core primatives supported by URDF: https://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link

box
cylinder
sphere

If you want to use a geometry that doesn't consist of one of those primatives you need to create a <mesh> representation of the link.
There's a recent thread talking about the many different ways to generate them here: https://discourse.ros.org/t/discuss-tools-and-best-practices-for-3d-robot-assets-urdf-sdformat-cad-etc/36997

Just use Python. You can easily write Python code to generate .ply files for the simple shapes. This format is (optionally) text based and not so complex. Most of the tools that support STL files in URDF (at least all ROS) support PLY as well. For instance, here would be a code to create a half-cylinder (there is no "semi-circle" in 3D).
import numpy as np


def generate_half_cylinder(radius, height, num_radial_segments, num_height_segments):
    # First create points
    vertices = []
    for i in range(num_height_segments + 1):
        z = height * i / num_height_segments
        for j in range(num_radial_segments + 1):
            theta = np.pi * j / num_radial_segments  # from 0 to pi
            x = radius * np.cos(theta)
            y = radius * np.sin(theta)
            vertices.append((x, y, z))

    # And then connect them
    faces = []
    for i in range(num_height_segments):
        for j in range(num_radial_segments):
            v0 = i * (num_radial_segments + 1) + j
            v1 = v0 + 1
            v2 = v1 + num_radial_segments + 1
            v3 = v0 + num_radial_segments + 1
            faces.append((v0, v1, v2))
            faces.append((v0, v2, v3))

    return vertices, faces

# And there is nothing magic about PLY:
def write_ply(filename, vertices, faces):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("ply\n")
        f.write("format ascii 1.0\n")
        f.write(f"element vertex {len(vertices)}\n")
        f.write("property float x\n")
        f.write("property float y\n")
        f.write("property float z\n")
        f.write(f"element face {len(faces)}\n")
        f.write("property list uchar int vertex_index\n")
        f.write("end_header\n")
        for vertex in vertices:
            f.write(f"{vertex[0]} {vertex[1]} {vertex[2]}\n")
        for face in faces:
            f.write(f"3 {face[0]} {face[1]} {face[2]}\n")

Once you have a shape, you can "plant" it in URDF or XACRO file at the needed location as usual, specifying translation, rotation and scale if needed. The co-ordinate system remains the same. Use some 3D tool like MeshLab to verify if the shape is correct.
